# json.loads and Redis in python 3.5

Tags: python, json, redis, binascii

I created a JSON object with json.dumps() and RPUSH(ed) it in a redis list.
When getting back the JSON with LRANGE ( redis.lrange() ) I receive a binary string

```
 b'{"si":"00:ff" ...
```

So json.loads() raises an error:
*** TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
How should I revert to ascii ?

Comment: How was the file before? lso have you tried json.load() intead?

Comment: It raises also an error:*** AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: I have the same problem but in Python3.6 is OK in local, and my server use py3.5 and get `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'` If you don't want to update py just use `simplejson` replace built in `json`. But I don't why in detail....Sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general you want to remember the acronym BADTIE:

```
Bytes
Are
Decoded
Text
Is
Encoded
```

If you have bytes, you run `my_bytes.decode()` to get text.

If you have text, you run `my_text.encode()` to get bytes. You can also specify the encoding if you know it, but it has a sensible default.