# How to send image in base 64 hex string with JSON.stringify()?

Tags: python, json, ajax

I am uploading an image file:

```
oFReader.readAsDataURL(fileObject);

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent){  
  var picture = oFReader.result; 
  (... continue)
```

And, ajaxing:

```
var dataDict = {'purpose':'newpicture', 'picture':picture};
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'https://mydomain.whatever',
  data:JSON.stringify(dataDict)
})
```

When I print out 'picture' variable, it is like:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk...
```

Now, I am getting a new error on my AWS with Python 3.5, which did not occur on my local with Python 3.6. On line:

```
import json


if(request.body):
  data = json.loads(request.body)
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

I am guessing that it is because [json.loads changed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

> Changed in version 3.6: s can now be of type bytes or bytearray. The
>   input encoding should be UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.

But, I thought that I was turning the image into base64 string. What am I sending? String or Bytes? How do I send this image as an string??

Comment: Try using `request.get().json()` instead of `json.loads(request.body)`

Comment: @Wamadahama Thanks for your response. I got error "AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'" And this is Django project to be clear.

Comment: This might provide some insight on how to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006093/json-loads-and-redis-in-python-3-5

Comment: @Wamadahama OK! Take a look! Thanks again! :)